# Game involving points on $[0,1]$

Tags: puzzle, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

You're given a list of $22$ points in $[0,1]$ (not necessarily distinct), and you're asked to select, at every iteration, $2$ points to be substituted by their midpoint. After $20$ iteration, you should end up with $2$ points. Is there a selection strategy that leads to $2$ points that are at most $10^{-3}$ apart independently of the distribution of the initial list? For $n$ starting points, what would be the optimal distance between the final $2$ points that one could achieve?

Comment: One strategy that comes to mind is, given $x_1\le x_2\le ... \le x_{22}$, selecting $x_1$ and $x_{22}$ as the substitution points, and iterating this. I have yet to completely analyze its behavior though.

Comment: This is a cool question, what's your motivation?

Comment: @forallepsilon I tried your tactic on MATLAB and it is pretty consistent. However, it can still happen that the final two points are further than $10^3$. In 10,000 trials, I've gotten the two points as close as $.007$.

Comment: @forallepsilon, your strategy fails on the instance where $x_i=0$ for $1\leq i\leq 10$ and $x_i=1$ for $11\leq i\leq22$. On that instance the final distance is $\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: @Katy Can you do better with that configuration, though? I haven't found a way.

Comment: You can if you first choose $x_{21}$ and $x_{22}$, then choose $x_{21}$ and $x_{20}$, and then follow your strategy.

Comment: @Katy Following forallepsilon's strategy, I don't see how your example is a counterexample. You actually end up with final distance being 0, assuming you order the points at every iteration.

Comment: I think @Rustyn is right that Katy's example does not work as it stated. But, if we consider the start configuration with $9$ zero points and $13$ ones, we will get nine $0.5$'s and four $1$'s after the first iteration of forallepsilon's strategy. After the 2nd iteration, one gets five $0.5$'s and four $0.75$'s; continuing this way, one ends up with two points a distance $1/64>10^{-2}$ apart (unless I am missing something).

Comment: @user2097 I agree with you, you end up with 1/64 = 0.015625 which shows that forallepsilon's strategy is flawed. However, in that scenario, I don't see how we could do any better than 1/64.

Comment: More generally, if the initial position has $F_{n+1}$ zeros and $F_{n+2}$ ones (with $F_i$ Fibonacci numbers), then forallepsilon's algorithm halts with two points $2^{-n}$ apart.

Comment: @user2097, you're right! that was the instance I had in mind ($9$ zeros and $13$ ones).

Comment: @Rustyn, it's possible to achieve $0$ on that instance
*  $1$, $0$ -> $1/2$.
*  $1$, $1$ -> $1$.
*  $1$, $0$ -> $1/2$.
*  $1$, $0$ -> $1/2$.
*  $1$, $0$ -> $1/2$.
*  $0$, $0$ -> $0$.
*  $1$, $1$ -> $1$.
*  $1$, $1$ -> $1$.
*  $1$, $0$ -> $1/2$.
*  $1$, $1$ -> $1$.
*  $1/2$, $1$ -> $3/4$.
*  $3/4$, $1$ -> $7/8$.
*  $1/2$, $0$ -> $1/4$.
*  $1/4$, $0$ -> $1/8$.
*  $1$, $1$ -> $1$.
*  $1/8$, $7/8$ -> $1/2$.
*  $1/2$, $1/2$ -> $1/2$.
*  $1$, $1/2$ -> $3/4$.
*  $1/2$, $0$ -> $1/4$.
*  $1/4$, $3/4$ -> $1/2$.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the case of $9$ zero's and $13$ one's we can get the final two points within $10^{-3}$. We do this by substituting so that after $8$ iterations, we have $1$ zero and $13$ one's and then successively "moving the leftmost point" to the right. So that, in the end, the final points are: $\sum_{i=1}^{12} \frac{1}{2^i}$ and $1$ so that their difference is $\frac{1}{2^{12}}$.

Comment: @Rustyn More than that, we can leave 2 zeros and 2 ones after 18 iterations, which leads to a final configuration of two coinciding points

Comment: I'm at a loss for finding a counterexample. This is a great problem

Comment: I found pretty much the same question here http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3608/process-on-finite-points-in-a-line/3611#3611 but I'm unable to follow the proposed hints!

Comment: @Katy: Yes, the question is the same. But the answer is unheplful. (And I don't see any hints at that link.)

Answer (score 7):

Consider the $n$-tuples ${\bf a}_n:=(0,0,\ldots,0,1)\in[0,1]^n$. I claim that for these ${\bf a}_n$ the optimal final distance $d_n$ is given by
$$d_n={1\over 2^{n-2}}\ .$$
*Proof.* This is certainly true for $n=2$. Assume that it is true for an $n\geq2$, and consider ${\bf a}_{n+1}$. At the first step of the process we can either average a $0$ with $1$, or average two zeros. Using the first option we arrive at ${\bf a}_n'=(0,0,\ldots,0,{1\over2})\in[0,1]^n$, and using the second option we arrive at ${\bf a}_n$. It follows that
$$d_{n+1}=\min\{{1\over2}d_n,d_n\bigr\}={1\over2}d_n\ .$$
Therefore the best "universal" constant $\delta_n$ is $\geq{1\over 2^{n-2}}$. It is easily checked that  $\delta_3={1\over2}$ (here the optimal strategy is to first average the extreme $x_k$). The following figure shows the optimal end result for the quadruple $(0,x,y,1)$. We can learn two things from this figure: When $n=4$ then we can always obtain a final difference $d\leq0.25={1\over 2^2}$, which implies $\delta_4={1\over4}$, and, more important: Things get *very complicated* with increasing $n$.

[image]

For $n=5$ one cannot draw such a figure. Instead one can do the following: Denote by $g(x,y,z)$ the optimal end result for the quintuple $(0,x,y,z,1)$. The following figure shows the $121$ graphs of the functions
$$g\left({j\over10},{k\over10},z\right)\qquad(0\leq z\leq 1)$$ for $0\leq j\leq 10$, $\>0\leq k\leq 10$. The figure supports the conjecture  $\delta_5={1\over 8}$. Exact computation gives
$$g(0,0,0)={1\over8},\qquad g\left(0,0,{3\over4}\right)={1\over8}\ .$$
[image]

Comment: "It follows that the best 'universal' constant is $\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}$": I'm having trouble making sense of this. Do you mean that the best "universal" constant must be $\ge \frac{1}{2^{n-2}}$?

Comment: @TonyK: You are of course right.

Comment: It seems to me that (0, ..., 0, a, 1) is harder for general a than a = 0, so 2^(-n+2) should not be sharp.

Comment: @Erik: See my update.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Nice graph! It'd be interesting to see it for larger n. If one wants one of the final points to be 0, then one cannot do better than (1+a)/2^(n-2). Otherwise, the final points are 1/2^k and a/2^l for some (k,l) such that k+l <= n-2. I don't think that distance can be made smaller than 1/2^(n-2) in general (in particular, not for a = 3/4 and n = 7).

Comment: A big contour plot might convey this better than a 3D plot, since the former has no visual obstructions due to the lack of depth.

Comment: @Semiclassical: If I had to choose, I would go for the 3D plot. But best of all would be _both_.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: What were the values of $x,y,z$ for the worst case found? Perhaps if you rounded them to some more or less obvious values, then fed them back to Mathematica, you would achieve $0.125$.

Comment: @TonyK: See my edit.

Comment: Oh, sorry $-$ you already achieved $0.125$ with your $(0,0,0,0,1)$, didn't you?

Comment: It seems that for even numbers $n\ge 8$, user2097's construction gives a higher value of $δ_n$ $−$ see my comments to that answer (and user2097's correction) for examples.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer but just an example in which the distance between two final points is always *greater* than $\delta_n=\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}$.

In fact, let $n$ be an even number. Consider an n-tuple $(0,\ldots,0,1-\varepsilon,1)$ with $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2^{n/2-2}}$. Note that the sum of all numbers after $i$th iteration is at least $(2-\varepsilon)/2^i$; therefore, two final points cannot be closer than $(2-\varepsilon)/2^{n-2}=(2+o(1))\delta_n$ if in some iteration we take the midpoint of two nonzero points.

Therefore, what we have to do on every move is *either* to cancel one of the zeros *or* to divide one of nonzero numbers by two. Then, we end up with two points $\frac{1}{2^p}$ and $\frac{1-\varepsilon}{2^q}$ with $p+q\leqslant n-2$. For sufficiently large $n$, the minimum of $\left|\frac{1}{2^p}-\frac{1-\varepsilon}{2^q}\right|$ is attained when $p=q=n/2-1$, and this minimum equals $\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n/2-1}}=\frac{1}{2^{n-3}}=2\delta_n$.

I hope this technique can lead to a much better lower bound being generalized to deal with the case of many nonzero points.

UPD1. Now I noted that this answer exploits the same idea as Erik's comment on Christian Blatter's answer.

UPD2. As TonyK pointed out in the comment, the tuple $(0,0,0,0,5/7,1)$ has a lower bound of $1/14$ for distance between final points.

Comment: Looks good to me. The best $\varepsilon$ for this layout is $2/(\alpha+1)$, where $\alpha = 2^{n/2-1}$; this gives $\delta'_n = \varepsilon/\alpha$, e.g. $\delta'_6 = 1/10, \delta'_8=1/36, \delta'_{10} = 1/136$.

Comment: The $n$-tuples for the above values of $\delta'_n$ are $(0,0,0,0,\dfrac{3}{5},1), (0,0,0,0,0,0,\dfrac{7}{9},1)$, and $(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,\dfrac{15}{17},1)$.

Comment: @TonyK I agree with the 2nd and 3rd of your examples, but the first of them seems wrong to me. In fact, the condition that 'minimum of $\left|\frac{1}{2^p}-\frac{1-\varepsilon}{2^q}\right|$ is attained when $p=q=n/2-1$' is true only if $\varepsilon\leqslant 1/4$, as far as I see. For instance, $(0,0,0,0,3/5,1)$ can be transformed to $(1/4,3/10)$ with resulting distance $1/20<1/2^4$.

Comment: Yes, you are quite right. I think it should be $(0,0,0,0,\dfrac{5}{7},1)$ for $\delta'_6 = 1/14$.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you! I think the example is correct, I added it to the answer.